# How exactly is the same-domain policy enforced?

Tags: ajax, subdomain, xss

Let's say I have a domain, `js.mydomain.com`, and it points to some IP address, and some other domain, `requests.mydomain.com`, which points to a different IP address. Can a `.js` file downloaded from `js.mydomain.com` make Ajax requests to `requests.mydomain.com`?

How exactly do modern browsers enforce the same-domain policy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no: for AJAX calls, you can only access the same hostname (and port / scheme) as your page was loaded from.

There are a couple of work-arounds: one is to create a URL in `foo.example.com` that acts as a reverse proxy for `bar.example.com`. The browser doesn't care where the request is actually fulfilled, as long as the hostname matches. If you already have a front-end Apache webserver, this won't be too difficult.

Another alternative is [AJAST](http://ajast.org/ajast/main), which works by inserting script tags into your document. I believe that this is how Google APIs work.

You'll find a good description of the same origin policy here: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot - AJAST looks like a great option.

Comment: FWIW, IE doesn't generally care about the port. http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/23/The-IE8-Native-XMLHttpRequest-Object.aspx

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the IP address matters not at all (in any browser)-- it's ONLY the protcol/scheme, host, and (in some cases) port that determine the origin. This means that two different origins served from the same IP *may not* communicate, and that the same origin served across multiple IPs a load balancer *may* communicate.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because the host name is different. Two pages are considered to be from the same origin if they have the same host, protocol and port.

From Wikipedia on [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy):

> The term "origin" is defined using the
>   domain name, application layer
>   protocol, and (in most browsers) TCP
>   port of the HTML document running the
>   script. Two resources are considered
>   to be of the same origin if and only
>   if all these values are exactly the
>   same.