# Retrieve JSON with StackOverflow API

Tags: javascript, ajax, stackexchange-api

I want to retrieve information from my Stack Overflow profile as JSON using the API.

So I use this link [http:/api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/401025/](http://http:/api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/401025/).

But when I make the request I get a file containing the JSON data. 
How do I deal with that file using Ajax?

Here is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/hJhfU/2/):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var req;

   getReputation();

   function getReputation(){
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('GET', 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/401025/');
      req.onreadystatechange = processUser;
      req.send();
   }

   function processUser(){       
       var res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
       alert('test');      
   }
  </script>
 </head>
```

The alert is never fired and `req.responseText` seems to be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Use jQuery. Manual AJAX makes people reading your code hate you and you are likely to make mistakes.

Comment: @ThiefMaster You're going to laugh when you see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note: **You cannot use Ajax to access another domain. (This is called the [same-domain policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929677/how-exactly-is-the-same-domain-policy-enforced).)**

However, the StackOverflow API supports JSONP callbacks, so here is a solution:

**Load in the script via a `<script>` tag.**

Create a function that does just that:

```
function load_script(src) {
   var scrip = document.createElement('script');
   scrip.src = src;
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scrip);
   return scrip; //just for the heck of it
}
```

Set up the callback function:

```
function soResponse(obj) {
   alert(obj.users[0].reputation);
}
```

Load it!

```
load_script('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/401025/?jsonp=soResponse');
```

Comment: @ArtWorkAD First of all, Ajax doesn't work on jsFiddle. Second of all, see my updated answer.

Comment: It seems that req.responseText is empty

Comment: what does that mean for me? Does that mean that I can not access my user profile using ajax?

Comment: @ArtWorkAD Yes that is what it means.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD See my updated answer, I think I solved this baby! :)

Comment: getting CORB issue

Answer (score 1):

For any future readers:

I wanted to get my Reputation without using oAuth and a whole library to do so. Thanks to Sebastien Horin's answer I easily could using the following:

```html
function get_reputation() {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/USER_ID?&site=stackoverflow';

    xhttp.open( "GET", url );
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            
            var json = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            
            console.debug( json );
            
        }       
    }
}

get_reputation();
```

*Note*: this uses API v2.3.

Answer (score 0):

there is a new API ( replace USER_ID )

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/[USER_ID]?&site=stackoverflow
```